# counting the blog ids and displaying the results in descending order in mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Counting the no of blog ids(same) and displaying the results in descending order.I am having recommended read section here i need to display the blogs based on the count of no of categories for a particular blog.My table looks like this
**blogs**

```
    blog_id|   image_path  | description
-------------------------------------------
    1      |   image.png   | description
    2      |   image1.png  | description
    3      |   image2.png  | description
    4      |   image3.png  | description
```

**blog_categories**

```
 blog_category_id   |  blog_id | category_id
-------------------------------------------
    1               |   1      | 1
    2               |   1      | 2
    3               |   2      | 3
    4               |   3      | 4
    5               |   3      | 2
    6               |   3      | 6
```

Here in blog_categories table blog_id  3 count is 3 and for 1 the count is 2 so while displaying the the results the first one should be

```
blog_id
3
1
2
```

It should the result in this format.But i am getting only one record from the query

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public function article()
    {
      $this->load->model('blogs_model');
      $data['records4'] = $this->blogs_model->get_all_recommended();
      $data['mainpage']='blogs';
      $this->load->view('templates/templatess',$data);        
    }
```

Model:

```
function get_all_recommended()
{ 
    $this->db->select('count(*),image_path,description');
    $this->db->from('blog_categories');
    $this->db->join('blogs AS B','B.blog_id=blog_categories.blog_id','INNER');
    $this->db->order_by("blog_categories.blog_id", "DESC");
    $this->db->limit('4,4');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
        { 
    return $query->result();
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

View:

```
<?php if(isset($records4) && is_array($records4)):?>
    <?php foreach ($records4 as $r):?> 
        <div class="clearfix float-my-children">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/blogimages/thumbs/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" width=100>
            <div class="blogclasstext134"><?php echo $r->blog_text;?></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_all_recommended()
{ 
    $this->db->select('B.blog_id,count(*),image_path,blog_title');
    $this->db->from('blog_categories');
    $this->db->join('blogs AS B','B.blog_id=blog_categories.blog_id','INNER');
    $this->db->join('categories AS C','C.category_id=blog_categories.category_id','INNER');
    $this->db->group_by('B.blog_id');
    $this->db->order_by("count(blog_categories.blog_id)", "DESC");      
    $this->db->limit('4,4');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    { 
        return $query->result();
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Correct answer for counting the blog_ids and displaying the results.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a COUNT(*) but no GROUP BY blog_id.

Comment: $this->db->select('count(*),image_path,blog_title');
$this->db->from('blog_categories');
$this->db->join('blogs AS B','B.blog_id=blog_categories.blog_id','INNER');
$this->db->join('categories AS C','C.category_id=blog_categories.category_id','INNER');
$this->db->group_by('B.blog_id');
$this->db->order_by("blog_categories.blog_id", "DESC");  
$this->db->limit('4,4');  Added this but it is not fetching the results in correct order